# Jade / Pug version of <template> </template> tags

Tags: node.js, pug, ejs, html5-template

I was working with a friend today, he uses EJS as templating and I'm using Jade / Pug, I saw something in his code, this part is useful for me but we can't find anything relating to this tag, any ideas ?

```
<template id="thumbTemplate">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-2">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <a href = "#">
                <img src = "">
            </a>
        </div>
        <p style="text-align: center; font-size: 20px"></p>
        <p style="text-align: center; font-size: 20px" id="score"></p>
        <p style="text-align: center; font-size: 20px" id="dist"></p>
    </div>
</template>
```

Thank for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to the "template" tag? If so, here is some information about this tag: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/template/

Comment: Thank you for the link ! I haven't find anything related to my problem, it doesn't specify that I can't use it in Pug.